# How to combine two Highcharts chart types?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Right now I have a simple column chart with following code using Highcharts:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    //some code
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: []
                },
                yAxis: {
                   //some code                        
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{point.y}'
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    //some code
                },
                series: []
            };

            $.getJSON("data/column.php", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data']; 
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });
```

I now want to add a line chart to the same container, using exactly the same options (despite of the chart type). The date is also served via JSON.

How can I achieve this?

What I did so far:
I created a second variable "options2" with values chart and series. 
Then I called

```
$.getJSON("data/line.php", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data']; 
                options2.series[1] = json[1];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options2);
            });
```

But that only shows the first column chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by passing the series option (chart type) directly via JSON. 
I added the "type:line" to the data array, which then overrides previously set options within the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should try use $.merge to prevent object edition.

Try this

```
        $.getJSON("data/column.php", function(json) {
            // Merge objects
            var newOptions = $.extend({}, options);

            // Edit new object instead of old
            newOptions.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
            newOptions.series[0] = json[1];

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart( newOptions );
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work (without showing an error in console log).
Possibly I missed a crucial part: I have a variable called `options2` which declares chart (renderTo and type) and series. 
But your variable does not merge the two variables `options`and `options2`, does it?

Comment: Yes, it doen't. For merge options use: $.extend({}, options, options2);

Comment: That doesn't work as well. With this code the chart type changes alternating (when refreshing the page) from column to line. 
I guess it's a problem with the series. According to Highcharts documentation the second (and so on) chart type(s) have to be set in the series array.